# PHP MYSQL USER ID in ARRAY

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table with a column "`responsibles`". There is an imploded array  separated with `|`.. The content looks like `1|5|74|86`. The numbers are user IDs.

How can i make a MYSQL Select like `in_array(USER_ID, ALL_IDs)`?

Cheers, n.

Comment: very bad db design. think about normalisation

Comment: Please show what you have tried and your research efforts.

Answer (score 3):

use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

```
find in set(USER_ID, replace( ALL_IDs,'|',',')
```

And as i wrote in my comment: "very bad db design. think about normalisation"